# How to do conditional cumulative sum which requires accessing previously calculated elements on the fly?

Tags: r

I am trying to do the following conditional cumulative sum efficiently in base R, but I am struggling with accessing previously calculated elements on the fly. Code with a for loop:

```
input <- c(6, 4, 8, 2, 2, 4, 2, 6)    
indx <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 5)
desired_out <- rep(0, length(input))
for (i in seq_along(desired_out)) {
    print(desired_out[i] <- desired_out[indx[i]] + input[i])
}
# [1] 6
# [1] 10
# [1] 18
# [1] 12
# [1] 14
# [1] 22
# [1] 14
# [1] 20
```

The desired output is the vector `c(6, 10, 18, 12, 14, 22, 14, 20)`. It's like a conditional cumulative sum because you can almost get the result by doing `cumsum(input)[indx] + input`.

Comment: may i ask why does this for loop not work for u? what kind of dimensions are you tackling?

Comment: millions of rows, but importantly, the rows are grouped so I want to use the split apply combine workflow using `data.table`.

Comment: I am not clear about the logic. How many elements you want to look back based on `indx` ? Can you explain one example maybe for `indx` =4 ?

Comment: the `indx` vector simply gives the index of the result vector to look up. The condition `indx <= seq_along(desired_out)` is always true so this index lookup never fails. For the value of the loop index `i = 5`, such that `indx[5] = 4`, the calculation will be `desired_out[5] = desired_out[4] + input[5] = 12 + 2 = 14`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If speed is of utmost concern, OP's code can be easily translated into C++ code using `Rcpp` as follows:

sample data:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(0L)
M <- 1e6
ngrps <- 1e3
DT <- data.table(input=sample(10, M, replace=TRUE),
    indx=sort(sample(ngrps, M, replace=TRUE)))

# DT <- data.table(input=c(6, 4, 8, 2, 2),    
#         indx=c(1, 1, 2, 2, 4))
```

cpp code:

```
library(Rcpp)
system.time(
    cppFunction(
    "NumericVector func(NumericVector input, NumericVector indx) {
        const int len = input.size();
        NumericVector ret(len, 0.0);
        for (int k=0; k<len; k++) {
            ret[k] = ret[indx[k]-1] + input[k];
        }
        return ret;
    }")
)
#  user  system elapsed 
#  0.04    0.05    6.64
```

Remember that C++ code uses zero-based indexing, hence the need for `indx[k]-1`.

Check against OP's example:

```
input <- c(6, 4, 8, 2, 2, 4, 2, 6)    
indx <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 5)
func(input, indx)
#[1]  6 10 18 12 14 22 14 20
```

Timing and sample call with `data.table` syntax:

```
system.time(DT[, func(input, indx)])
#  user  system elapsed 
#  0.00    0.01    0.02
```

Speed comparison to R loop

```
M <- 1e6
ngrps <- 1e3
input <- sample(10, M, replace=TRUE),
indx <- sort(sample(ngrps, M, replace=TRUE)))
microbenchmark(
  rcpp = func(input, indx),
  Rloop = {
    desired_out <- rep(0, length(input))
    for (i in seq_along(desired_out)) {
      desired_out[i] <- desired_out[indx[i]] + input[i]
    }},
  unit = 'relative',
  times = 100)

# Unit: relative
# expr       min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
# rcpp   1.00000  1.00000 1.000000  1.00000 1.000000 1.0000000   100
# Rloop 14.80781 11.37963 6.712257 10.44288 6.244126 0.7554706   100
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I am currently constrained to not use Rcpp but that might change in the future. :(

Comment: I am accepting this answer even though it doesn't do exactly what I want. However, the benchmark that shows that the R loop (with preallocated memory) is only an order of magnitude slower than a Rcpp solution is very useful.

Comment: What is it that you want?

Comment: I hope I encapsulated what I wanted in the first sentence of my post: "I am trying to do the following conditional cumulative sum efficiently in base R". I don't consider that the `Rcpp` solution satisfies this, even though it is useful.

Answer (score 0):

`sapply` should be faster

```
sapply(1:length(input), function(i){

  desired_out[i]<<-desired_out[indx[i]] + input[i]

})
[1]  6 10 18 12 14 22 14 20
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I do not think this is any faster, nor significantly different from the for loop I provided.

Comment: Ack, you're right. I had left in your call to `print` when I benchmarked it, but obviously you don't need that in your final solution.